# Why do my desk top icons disapear after opening libra office, Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, icons, crash

When I open and close a libra office file on my desktop, it disapears from the dektop.  So do many of the other icons.  This even caused a crash when I closed a libra file.  I can still see them in Files, but not on my desktop.  Note I am running three external monitors.  Not sure if that somehow is the issue?

Comment: The gnome shell extension used to manage the desktop icons is likely malfunctioning. Either stop putting files on the desktop (you can access them easier from the file manager) or disable the extension and install an improved version, Desktop Icons NG

Comment: Ok, thank you for that. cheers.